# How to export all the group headers from a DataWindow in an XML from PowerBuilder

Tags: xml, export, powerbuilder

We are working with PowerBuilder 11.5. We have problem of export to XML file all the group headers from a DataWindow. We are only export the first one. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the XML export in DataWindows is that they work on the data set portion of the DataWindow, not the UI portion. The concept of a group header is a UI implementation, so I don't think you'll get anything out of the DataWindow's functionality directly.

If it were me, I'd try to leverage the PBDOM and build the XML the way I wanted. I'd loop through the rows, and when the group changed, push the extra attributes, etc... out to the DOM.

Good luck,

Terry.